# Xamarin.Forms ListView custom cell is not selectable

Tags: listview, selection, xamarin.forms

I created a custom cell:

```
public class TextCell2 : ViewCell
{
    public TextCell2()
    {
        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children =
            {
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "Test"
                },
                new Button
                {
                    Text = "Test 2"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I don't add any child, the cell is selectable.
If I add any child, the cell can't be select anymore.

plz help me how to use selection in custom view.

Comment: trying - adding  'IsEnabled = false' to both the Label and Button - it could be that they are capturing the input so the cell doesn't get the tap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set InputTransparent=true to both your label and button.

They are currently catching the click. InputTransparent will let the click go through to the parent element.